# JavaScript function for modal popup only works for the first element

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on clothing shopping website where on main page of my website has different clothing displayed. on every cloth there is add to cart button that opens popup modal on click but i am facing a problem that modal popup only display first dress details on every dress modal popup means it is displaying only first dress price and quantity on all buttons.
here is the code:

```
<button class="update fa fa-shopping-cart " id="mpopupLink1" onclick="openModal2()" title="Add to Cart" type="image"  style=" margin-top: 90px; margin-left:110px;   width: 35px; height: 35px; background: white; "  /></button>

// here is starting modal popup
<div id="mpopupBox1" class="mpopup1">
    <!-- mPopup content -->
    <div class="mpopup1-content">
        <div class="mpopup1-head">
            <span class="close8">×</span>
              <h2 style="font-family:Cooper Black;"><center>Add to Cart</center></h2>    
           </div>
        <div class="mpopup1-main" >
<br/>
<br/>         
  <p><b>Product Code: <?php echo $row['id']; ?></b></p> 
            <div style="margin: 30px 40px 40px 250px;">
                         <p id="demo"><font size="6" ><b>PKR</b></font>

     <input name="price" type="number" id="price" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>" readonly> </font> <br/>

</p> 
                              </div>
           <div style="margin: -75px 60px 40px 0px;" >
                        <label><font size="4">Quantity</font></label>   
   </div>  
                <input  style="margin-left: 335px; margin-top: -40px; width: 135px;" type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="button button4 add-to-cart" value="Add to Cart">
    </div>
        <div class="mpopup1-foot">
           <!-- <p>created by CodexWorld</p> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
// here is javascript function

<script type="text/javascript">
 var mpopup1 = document.getElementById('mpopupBox1');


// get the link that opens the mPopup
var mpLink1 = document.getElementById("mpopupLink1");

// get the close action element
var close8 = document.getElementsByClassName("close8")[0];

// open the mPopup once the link is clicked
mpLink1.onclick = function() {
    mpopup1.style.display = "block";
}

var images1 = document.querySelectorAll('button[title="Add to Cart"]');
for(var i=0, len = images1.length; i < len; i++){
    images1[i].addEventListener('click', openModal2);
}

  function openModal2() {
      mpopup1.style.display = "block";          
   }


// close the mPopup once close element is clicked
close8.onclick = function() {
    mpopup1.style.display = "none";
}

// close the mPopup when user clicks outside of the box

 </script>
```

Comment: have you inspect element dress details on every dress modal popup ?
what code you use for looping to display content ?

Comment: i am using while loop to display all dresses on main page

Comment: Because that's how you coded. You have rendered modal popup with first product details using `php` and your are doing show/hide. Nothing going to change the modal popup details. Try using `Ajax` for updating modal content.

Comment: can anyone please update this code so that it can work for all image buttons?

Comment: inside your while loop, do you always print mpopupLink1, mpopupBox1, mpopup1  ? and what is myModal2() function do ?

Comment: no while loop is only for geeting images and details from database and displaying. sorry myModal2 function was written by mistake i changed it

Comment: Please anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your product details to the button(input type image) as custom attributes. When the button is clicked, it will fetch the data attributes of that button.

Here's a working example below:

```js
// your dynamic popup box
var mpopup1 = document.getElementById('mpopupBox1');

// popup box close button
var close8 = document.getElementsByClassName("close8")[0];

// open modal and update content
function openModal2(item) {
  var image = item.getAttribute('data-image');
  var price = item.getAttribute('data-price');
  var code = item.getAttribute('data-code');

  document.getElementById('price').value = price;
  document.getElementById('image').src = image;
  document.getElementById('code').innerHTML = code;
  mpopup1.style.display = "block";
}

// close the mPopup once close element is clicked
close8.onclick = function() {
  mpopup1.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<input class="update fa fa-shopping-cart" id="mpopupLink1" onclick="openModal2(this)" title="Add to Cart" type="image" style="margin-top: 90px; margin-left:110px; width: 35px; height: 35px; border: 1px solid" data-image="https://gloimg.gamcdn.com/G/pdm-product-pic/Clothing/2016/10/15/source-img/20161015092246_60853.jpg"
  data-code="1122333" data-price="100" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/dress-2/60/long_dress_1-256.png" />

<input class="update fa fa-shopping-cart " id="mpopupLink1" onclick="openModal2(this)" title="Add to Cart" type="image" style=" margin-top: 90px; margin-left:110px; width: 35px; height: 35px; border: 1px solid" data-image="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/58/bf/0c/58bf0c2eff5c91d5908480de69072e89--dresses-on-sale-a-line-dresses.jpg"
  data-price="200" data-code="445566" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/131762/isolated/lists/f8bc76e174b4c43d78c962f7e6f06f07-pink-women-s-cloth.png" />


<div id="mpopupBox1" class="mpopup1" style="display:none">
  <!-- mPopup content -->
  <div class="mpopup1-content">
    <div class="mpopup1-head">
      <span class="close8">×</span>
      <h2 style="font-family:Cooper Black;">
        <center>Add to Cart</center>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="mpopup1-main">
      <figure>
        <img src="" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228" id="image">
      </figure>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <p><b>Product Code: <span id="code"></span></b></p>
      <div style="margin: 30px 40px 40px 250px;">
        <p id="demo">
          <font size="6"><b>PKR</b></font>

          <input name="price" type="number" id="price" value="5000" readonly> </font> <br/>

        </p>
      </div>
      <div style="margin: -75px 60px 40px 0px;">
        <label><font size="4">Quantity</font></label>
      </div>
      <input style="margin-left: 335px; margin-top: -40px; width: 135px;" type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="button button4 add-to-cart" value="Add to Cart">
    </div>
    <div class="mpopup1-foot">
      <!-- <p>created by CodexWorld</p> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is not dynamically working. i don't know how many records are in my database so i want modal popup works dynamically for all images. may be loop can be used to do this

Comment: those two example buttons could be in a loop, thats how you do it!

Comment: i have tried but not working. can you please edit this code for loop?

Comment: i think loop should be on modal popup?

Comment: in your php code, you just have to put inside your  loop one input type image tag something like this: `foreach($images as $image):  <input class="update fa fa-shopping-cart" id="mpopupLink1" onclick="openModal2(this)" title="Add to Cart" type="image" style="margin-top: 90px; margin-left:110px; width: 35px; height: 35px; border: 1px solid" data-image="<?= $image['large_image'] ?>"
  data-code="<?= $image['code'] ?>" data-price="<?= $image['price'] ?>" src="<?= $image['small_image'] ?>" /> endforeach;`